# Style tags not coming in mui 5 react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app, prerender

I have built 2 projects in React.js, one is using material ui 4 and another one is using mui5. Both the websites are working fine and styling is also perfect. I have noticed that in the project which is built using material ui 4, I can see style tags are loading whereas in the project which is built using mui 5 style tag with CSS is not there. PFB the screenshot.

I am using pre-render.io for prerendering website, due to the above behavior website built using material ui 5 is showing proper styling to the bot whereas, in the case of the mui5 website, no CSS is loading for the bot.

**MUI 5 project:**

[image]

**Material UI 4 project:**

[image]

I have utilized both the material version as per the doc on their website. The only difference is mui5 project is built with CRA and the material ui 4 project is built with a custom webpack.

How can I load mui 5 styling in case of prerendering using prerender.io